# In windows 10 after resetting it is showing Other user in the Login page. How do I login in my system?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, login-screen

I recently reset my Windows 10 in Asus Vivobook S406U.

After reset it is giving me a login screen as "Other user". In that, if I type my previous user id it is not working.

I ran it in safe mode (pressing Shift and restart). It opened in Administrator I pressed (windows + r and ran cmd)

In the command prompt, I ran the below commands to activate my administrator account.

1. net user administrator /active: yes
2. net user administrator Password123

I restarted my PC and logged in via my administrator account so as to create a user id and deactivate the administrator account accordingly.

but I am unable to create any new user the windows key or the search button nothing is working.

and on logging in I am getting the error.

"C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop is unavailable. If this location is on this PC, make sure that the device or drive is connected or the disc is inserted, then try again. If the location is on a network, make sure that you're connected to the network or internet, then try again. If the location still cannot be found, it might have been moved or deleted."

Also, file explorer is also not working.

I do not have the Windows 10 DVD/CD along with my laptop. While I purchased it.

Comment: okay and how will I re-install it. I mean what option via troubleshoot

Comment: then can you elaborate me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This process worked for me after I had to re-image my company laptop:

1. Open Start -> Run -> `secpol.msc` to open the Local Security Policy control panel.
2. Navigate to `Local Policies -> Security Options`.
3. Set `Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in` and `Interactive logon: Don't display username at sign-in` to `Disabled`.

[Local Security Policy control panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7THk.png)

4. Close the control panel.
5. Open an administrator command window.
6. Run `gpupdate /force` (You may need to connect to VPN if this is a company group policy.)
7. Test by locking/unlocking Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I do remember something similar happening to me with Win8.1 but couldnt remember the solution off the top of my head. Looked around the MS forums a bit and found something that makes sense

IIRC this is not destructive, but I would creat a backup of anything you have on your desktop just in case

Open Windows File Explorer

On the View Ribbon, check the box marked 'Hidden Items'

C:\users\Default\

Right click and copy the Desktop folder contained in the Default Folder

Navigate to: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile

Right click and Paste the Desktop folder into the systemprofile folder

Restart (not shut down) your PC

As far as the other user thing on the login screen, see if it still does that after creating a new user and applying the above fix.
If it doesnt fix it, I know there is a policy setting that sets it to not show the list of users and do this instead.
I believe you can access policy with secpol.msc or gpedit.msc, but you can also get to it from control panel.